# Problem with jQuery autocomplete and lucene

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, lucene

I use jQuery autocomplete in a jsp and get my searchresults from a servlet, where a Lucene Index is searched against the given term that should be autocompleted.
Thats the code of the autocomplete in the jsp:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#QRY_ItemQuickSearch_enc").autocomplete("<%=autoSuggestAction%>",
        {
            onItemSelect:selectItem,
            minChars:3,
            maxItemsToShow:10,
            cacheLength:10,
            matchSubset:10
        }
    );
});
```

The Servlet is called by the expression: autoSuggestAction.

Thats no problem so far.

My Index is very large and if i use for a special term (f.e: 123) where Lucene does not find anything, the function does not display anything (as wished). If i want to further type in the character "4", so the complete searchterm is now "1234", i also get no results (as predicted). Notice: the Search function repeats.

**Now my concrete problem:**

If i type a search string, which is a thousand times(or many more) in the index, Lucene cannot handle this query and throws an "TooManyClausesException". I kniow that I can increase the value for the Booleanquery, but that will cost too much memory. Instead I display a result, that is written back to the input field and shows the user to further define the searchstring. But if I now type a character into the input field, the autocomplete method is not called again. 
Can somebody help me in this case?

Comment: I solved the problem.
I edited the "requestData(q)" function in the source code of jquery.autocomplete. I inserted comments to the lines

if (data) { 
   receiveData(q, data);
}

Now my search engine shows the desired results. 
Cya

Comment: Good that you found a solution. You should post it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise this question will look unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

The original requester solved the problem by editing the "requestData(q)" function in the source code of jquery.autocomplete.

He/she commented the line:

```
    if (data) { receiveData(q, data); }
```

Now the search engine shows the desired results.